# Opel Corsa 1.7dti utility 2005 Fuel Delivery Problem

Tags: starting, fuel-system, opel, corsa

I have an opel corsa 1.7dti utility 2005 model. I serviced my car recently and after I serviced the car it wouldn't start. It turned over but it wouldn't start. I primed the diesel filter by pouring some diesel in there, it started and ran for about a minute but then it stalled. I thought it might be the fuel pump but when I phoned the agents for a new fuel pump they said the fuel pump lasts forever on these cars I should rather check the fuel pump control module. This is a very expensive part to replace. So my question is how do I know if the problem is the fuel pump or the fuel pump control module without replacing either one of those?

Comment: You should check the fuel pressure at the output of the fuel pump as a starting point.

Comment: You should have made sure the new filter was full of fuel, not just added some... If there is too much air, it starts then cuts out. Re-prime the system to get the air out.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a priming procedure for this car?  Some cars it is a simple as turning the key on and letting the pump run until the ECU turns it off, then repeating this procedure several times before starting the engine.

Comment: Perhaps buying a Haynes, Chilton manual can help if you're a diyer. Subscribing to Alldata or Mitchell provides online factory service manuals at reasonable cost.

Comment: What enginecode? Z17dtj or z17dth?